# composed mysql query working but if parametrized in mysqli don't working

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have a search page with 3 terms (seach parameter, postal code, and type of activity)

I have done a function to compose the sql: (this is not the real function, just a simplified one). You can use it with the parameter(s) that you want to filter or without parameter to get all.

```
function get_items($search="",$postal_code="",$activity=""){
global $db; //this is the $db=new mysqli(...) in other include file
$where="";
if ($s!=""){
    $s="%".$search."%";
    $where=" AND ((item.name like '".$s."') OR (item.description like '".$s."'))";
}
if($postal_code!=""){
    if (strlen($postal_code)==5){
         $where=" AND (item.postal_code like '".$postal_code."')";
    }
}

if($activity!=""){
    if (m_is_integer($postal_code)){ //m_is_integer returns true if is an integer
         $where=" AND (item.activity =".$activity.")";
    }
}
$sql="select ....... from -..... where .....".$where." order by ......"
//yes, I know I don't need to prepare the query 
$stmt=$db->prepare($sql); 
$result=$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$item_array=Array();
if (($result!=false) && ($stmt->num_rows>0)){
     //do things and populate the array $item_array
}
$stmt->close();
return $item_array;
}
```

This functions works, The sql is right composed, you put any parameter or none and return an array of items.

I want to make the parametrized query, and this is my approach:

```
function get_items_parametrized($search="",$postal_code="",$activity=""){
global $db; //this is the $db=new mysqli(...) in other include file
$where="";
$bind_array=Array();
if ($s!=""){
    $s="%".$search."%";
    $where=" AND ((item.name like ?) OR (item.description like ?))";
    $bii=Array("s",$s);
    $bind_array[]=$bii;
    $bii=Array("s",$s);
    $bind_array[]=$bii;
}
if($postal_code!=""){
    if (strlen($postal_code)==5){
         $where=" AND (item.postal_code like ?)";
         $bii=Array("s",$postal_code); //yes, is a string in the database
         $bind_array[]=$bii;
    }
}

if($activity!=""){
    if (m_is_integer($postal_code)){ //m_is_integer returns true if is an integer
         $where=" AND (item.activity = ?)";
         $bii=Array("i",$activity);
         $bind_array[]=$bii;
    }
}
$sql="select ....... from -..... where .....".$where." order by ......"
$stmt=$db->prepare($sql);
//go to bind data to search
$bind_type="";
$bind_params=Array();

foreach($bind_array as $b){
    $bind_type.=$b[0];
    $bind_params[]=$b[1];
    /* Approach 1: */
    $stmt->bind_param($b[0],$b[1]); 
}
/* Approach 2: */
$stmt->bind_param($bind_type,$bind_params); 
$result=$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$item_array=Array();
if (($result!=false) && ($stmt->num_rows>0)){
     //do things and populate the array $item_array
}
$stmt->close();
return $item_array;
}
```

This function is always returning an empty $item_array Array () not an Array(Array(),Array()) that will be possible if I don't bind the results ok, the execute is not returning any results.

I also tried to do:

```
/* attempt 3 */
$data=Array();
$data[0]="";
foreach($bind_array as $b){
    $data[]=$b1;
    $bind_type.=$b[0];
}
$data[0]=$bind_type;
```

To compose an array like ('ssi',$s,$postal_code,$activity) to call to call_user_func_array():

```
call_user_func_array(array(&$stmt, 'bind_param'), $data);
```

I also try:

```
call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $data);
```

And this approach is still returning no data.

What can I try now to make it work with parametrized querys?

Any help will be welcome :D

Comment: `bind_param` requires the parameters to be references, `call_user_func_array` doesn't pass references any more.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple: **don't use mysqli** with prepared statements.
It's unusable with prepared statements.
**Use PDO** instead.
This **is** the answer. Mysqli is your problem and you have to solve it.

With PDO your code will be 3 times shorter and working.

If you want to stick with mysqli, another way would be to get rid of prepared statements and implement your own placeholders, but some knowledge required. However, it will let you build conditional queries easier:

```
$w = array();
$where = '';
if ($one) $w[] = $db->parse("one = ?s",$one); 
if ($two) $w[] = $db->parse("two IN (?a)",$two);
if ($tre) $w[] = $db->parse("tre <= ?i",$tre);
if (count($w)) $where = "WHERE ".implode(' AND ',$w);
$data = $db->getArr("SELECT * FROM table ?p LIMIT ?i,?i",$where, $start,$per_page);
```

Comment: for a 'I have time' solution I will try, but now it's not possible to use pdo, it's disabled in the server and all the app is with mysqli (I'm not going to make one connection string just for one function). Thanks

Comment: you can use [safemysql](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql/blob/master/safemysql.class.php) then. it will let you build conditional queries and it is using mysqli. I'll an an example to my answer.

Comment: I will try, but I don't understand why don't work my parametrized query.